# Can players on different teams work together to attack a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

While taking a gym, when I made it neutral and was just about to take it for my team, a member of team instinct took it. I am in team Mystic and my friend is in Team Valor. So can we two both take it together.

The reason I am not testing it myself is because I am extremely low on resources( like only 2 or 3 potions and no superpotions ).

Comment: I'm pretty sure. But all my friends are on the same team, so my experience comes from random people nearby assisting in the fight and then the gym turning a different colour than my own team. but it could have been a third party

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Players on the two opposing teams will *both* have a net negative effect on the Gym in question. The battles won't be considered "allied", so you don't get the time boost or see other Pokemon on the battle screen, but both will drop the Gym's Level and Prestige.

One thing to note, though, is that the game has no "protection" mechanism. Once a Gym is lost, it is free for any player at all to capture it, regardless of teams. Therefore, if you are battling with friends, it's a good idea to have a dedicated "sniper" to claim the gym as soon as it falls.

Comment: to supplement your last point: I think it's also good especially when your playing solo, to wait for the person on the other team to take the gym. This way you can just wait until they leave and then have an easy fight against only a single pokemon gym. Then you can go and collect more gyms. Otherwise if you snipe it, it's likely that the other team's player(s) will stay and take the gym over again, so you won't get any extra defender bonus (unless you are collecting immediately.)